# How to execute a node-schedule job immediately and recurring after every 30 mins

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have written a nodejs program, and want to schedule it using node-schedule npm, recurring every 30 mins. 
I have scheduled it using

```
var nodeSchedule = require('node-schedule');
nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('* /30 * * * *',require('./devModules.js').runDev);
```

Instead of executing immediately it is going for a sleep of 30 mins and then executing every 30 mins. 
How do I schedule it immediately and reoccur after every 30 mins?

Please help.

Comment: you can simply use  setInterval function for that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 2):

I think node-scheduler does not support this and things like this can be done with setInterval but to use it with corn use "corn" module:-  [Cron npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```js
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var myJob = new cronJob('0 */10 * * * *', function(){
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
},function(){

},true); 

// true value will start it once you start cron job
```

Let us know if it is helpful.